# Frequency table showing all instances of Table A in Table B -- Very large datasets

Tags: r

I'm looking to make a table that shows how many times a cell in Table A shows up in Table B. My data is over a million lines long so my solutions have either timed out, or been insufficient.

Here is what I have currently

Table A

```
| Column1 | 
| --------| 
| ABCDEFG | 
| HIJKLMN |
```

Table B

```
| Column1  | Column2        |
| -------- | -------------- |
| ABCDEFG  | RUWNVIP        |
| ABCDEFG  | HIJKLMN        |
```

I want to make

```
| ID       | Occurrences in Table B column1 | 
| -------- | ------------------------------ |
| ABCDEFG  | 2                              |
| HIJKLMN  | 0                              |
```

My best current code is to do this with a function

```
TableBcount <-function(x){
  countAB <- ifelse(x %in% Table B, +1 , +0 )
}

Table A <- sapply(as.list(TableA$Column1), TableBcount)
```

This only returns a table of 1's (if the ID is found in Table B) and 0's (if the ID is not found), like so:

| ID | Occurrences in Table B column1 |
| --- | --- |
| ABCDEFG | 1 |
| HIJKLMN | 0 |

Any suggestions on how to get it to count instead of giving a simple 1-found, 0-not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a join and count number of non-NA values in `column2` -

```
library(dplyr)

TableA %>%
  left_join(TableB, by = 'Column1') %>%
  group_by(Column1) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(!is.na(Column2)))

#  Column1 Count
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 ABCDEFG     2
#2 HIJKLMN     0
```

In base R :

```
stack(sapply(TableA$Column1, function(x) sum(TableB$Column1 == x)))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help! The base R suggestion worked quickly and cleanly. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check values in one column of second database, use either of these

```
tblA <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Col1 = c("ABCD", "EFGH")
        )
tblB <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              colA = c("ABCD", "ABCD"),
              colB = c("EFGH", "HIJK")
        )

tblA$occurences <- apply(tblA, 1, \(x) sum(sapply(tblB$colA, \(y) sum(x == y))))

#OR

library(tidyverse)
tblA %>% mutate(ocuurences = map_dbl(Col1, \(xy) sum(map_dbl(tblB$colA, ~ sum(.x == xy)))))

  Col1 ocuurences
1 ABCD          2
2 EFGH          0
```

---

Below answers are to check values of table1 in all columns of table 2

```r
tblA$occurences <- apply(tblA, 1, \(x) sum(sapply(tblB, \(y) sum(x == y)))) #R version 4.1.0

tblA
#>   Col1 occurences
#> 1 ABCD          2
#> 2 EFGH          1
```

---

`tidyverse` style of above

```r
library(tidyverse)
tblA %>% mutate(ocuurences = map_dbl(Col1, \(xy) sum(pmap_dbl(tblB, ~ sum(c(...) == xy)))))

#>   Col1 ocuurences
#> 1 ABCD          2
#> 2 EFGH          1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
tblA <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Col1 = c("ABCD", "EFGH")
)
tblB <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  colA = c("ABCD", "ABCD"),
  colB = c("EFGH", "HIJK")
)

setDT(tblA)
setDT(tblB)

tblB[tblA, .N, on = c("colA == Col1"), by = .EACHI]
#>    colA N
#> 1: ABCD 2
#> 2: EFGH 0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This should work (very) fast even for millions of rows

```
library(data.table)

# Sample data
DT1 <- fread(" Column1 
ABCDEFG 
HIJKLMN")
  
DT2 <- fread("Column1 Column2        
   ABCDEFG  RUWNVIP        
   ABCDEFG  HIJKLMN")

# Summarise DT2 and perform an update join on DT1
DT1[DT2[, .N, by = .(Column1)], Occ := i.N, on = .(Column1)]
#    Column1 Occ
# 1: ABCDEFG   2
# 2: HIJKLMN  NA

# Replace NA with 0
DT1[ is.na(Occ), Occ := 0]
#    Column1 Occ
# 1: ABCDEFG   2
# 2: HIJKLMN   0
```